# Android Studio how to order by variable with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have this code which gets the value of distance between user's localition and location of object from the Firebase Database, i want to order by "distanceKm" (which is a float, the distance between user's localition and location) in this for "for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { "

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference perdidosUbiRef = rootRef.child("Perdidos");
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                LatLng ubicacion;//ubicacion va canviant a mesurea recorrent base de dades
                Anuncio a;
                //AGAFA UBICACIO CADA VEGADA CARREGA BASE DE DADES
                final LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                boolean network_enabled = mgr.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Location locationUser = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                //-----
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    String descripcion = ds.child("descripción").getValue(String.class);
                    Float Lat = ds.child("ubicación").child("lat").getValue(Float.class);
                    Float Long = ds.child("ubicación").child("long").getValue(Float.class);
                    Log.d("ValuesofLat", String.valueOf(Lat));
                    Log.d("ValuesofLat", String.valueOf(Long));
                    ubicacion = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Lat)), Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(Long)));//crea markers


                   //distancia dos puntos con ubicación usuario.
                    Location locationPet = new Location("locationPet");
                    locationPet.setLatitude(Lat);
                    locationPet.setLongitude(Long);
                    float distanceMeters = locationUser.distanceTo(locationPet);//calcula distancia
                    float distanceKm =distanceMeters/1000; //per posar en km
                    String distanceKmString = String.format("%.02f", distanceKm);//pasar a string distancia i a 2 decimales
                    Log.i("ubicacionGaleria", "Distancia de "+name+"coordenadas= "+locationUser.getLatitude()+" "+locationUser.getLongitude()+" "+Lat+Long+"de ti: "+distanceKmString);

                    a = new Anuncio(name, distanceKmString, R.drawable.icon);
                    anuncioList.add(a);

                    Log.d("ValuesofLat", name);
                    Log.d("ValuesofLat", descripcion);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
```

Thx!!!!!

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort a list with comparator. Here is a example:

```
List<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    myList.add(ds.getValue(MyObject.class));
}
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
        // Or if you want to sort reverse just return 
        // return o2.getDistance() - o1.getDistance();
        return o1.getDistance() - o2.getDistance();
    }
});
```

Or if you like elegant solutions you can try this [library](https://github.com/Link184/Respiration) to wrap all firebase logic under rxJava patterns and just sort your lists with rx "sort" operator

Comment: Isn't there a API from firebase to order by variables??

Comment: @FairyBand Sure, you can subscribe to a list and sort it, or to get firebase response as rxJava observable and apply "sort" before subscribing :)

Comment: If you want to sort the result inside a firebase you must use firebase fire storage service instead of firebase realtime database

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to implement the Comparable interface.
Then in the CompareTo method, compare the float values.
After that you can .sort the list you have.

Would look something like this:

```
public class Anuncio implements Comparable<Anuncio> {
private float distanceKm;

@Override
public int compareTo(Anuncio other) {
    return this.distanceKm.compareTo(other.distanceKM);

}
```

Comment: my question is about how to order by this value with Firebase hahah

Comment: Ah i'm sorry, I misunderstood you.
I don't think Firebase has the possibility to use an expression inside a query. You would need to do this after you have retrieved the data.